# How to 'disable are you sure you want to navigate away from this page' in post-new , have tried MANY solutions of onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onbeforeunload

Hey I'm making a custom backend for Wordpress, it's a bit 'ghetto' but it turned out to be bigger than expected so I'm running with it. Works perfectly fine stylistically and functionally but for some reason if I submit a new post with it, I get "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" or whichever browser equivalent.

I've tried a shitton of variations of onbeforeunload = null, returning blank functions, etc, none of the solutions have worked on any browser, so I assume it's something to do with Wordpress backend constantly updating...?, I read that it might be a factor that you can't bind onbeforeunload like a normal event as well, so a combination of these two makes me wonder, how can I permanently silence "are you sure" notices on a page, no questions asked?

It seems everywhere on the web is a variation of this question and/or setting the onbeforeunload null worked for them, it does not in any sense for me, even in inline JS onthe form. I have no idea why it's even triggering, I assume I moved something when reconstructing the WP submit form that causes it to ungroup data... or something, but I just need to silence all dialog from this page that is "save changes", that's all, seems like it's easy enough with a bind/event handler but they haven't worked and I don't quite get how the event works.

I've tried this and some other binds thus far, as well as putting return onbeforeunload null function inline the form

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

return null;
}

window.onbeforeunload = null;


jQuery('a, input').click(function(){

window.onbeforeunload = null;

});
```

Comment: Did you answer here work? Please vote/accept it if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the events were registered using jquery with `$(window).on('beforeunload'` you can remove them using `$(window).off('beforeunload'`

This example demonstrates the `click` event, but it works the same with the `beforeunload` event:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('click', function() {
    alert(1);
  });
  $(window).on('click', function() {
    alert(2);
  });
  
  $(window).off('click')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```